# Why can't a dart generic class determine its type based on constructor

Tags: generics, flutter, dart

I am writing my own MyFutureBuilder for my FutureBuilders do the same thing every time (except working with the snapshot data for which I specify my separate function).

```
typedef MyFutureBuilderBuildFunction<T> = Widget Function(T snapshotData);

class MyFutureBuilder<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final MyFutureBuilderBuildFunction<T> builder;
  final Future<T> future;

  MyFutureBuilder({this.future, @required this.builder})
      : assert(builder != null);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyFutureBuilderState(future: future, builder: builder);
  }
}

class MyFutureBuilderState<T> extends State<MyFutureBuilder<T>> {
  MyFutureBuilderBuildFunction<T> builder;
  Future<T> future;

  MyFutureBuilderState({this.future, @required this.builder})
      : assert(builder != null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<T>(
      future: future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return builder(snapshot.data);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }

        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

When I instantiate it with

```
Future<Article> _article;
MyFutureBuilder(
    future: _article,
    builder: (snapshotData) {
```

the type of snapshotData is **dynamic** and not **Article**. 
Can't the type T be automatically be determined from the type of _article, Future?

When I seperately give the type to MyFutureBuilder (which is IMHO redundant)

```
Future<Article> _article;
MyFutureBuilder<Article>(
    future: _article,
    builder: (snapshotData) {
```

the type of snapshotData is of course Article.

Comment: You mean when accessing `snapshotData.runtimeType` and printing that?

Comment: Well observed. Since annotating a different type to `snapshotData` is going to cause a compile time error, seems like Dart should be able to autocast `snapshotData` to `Article`. I think most of us cannot answer **why** this happens, though. I suggest you to open an issue for that: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues

Answer (score 0):

Because dart is type safe language.

In 1st code You should cast the returned snapshotData to the type you need before using it

```
Future<Article> _article;
MyFutureBuilder(
  future: _article,
  builder: (snapshotData) {
    Article article = snapshotData as Article;
  }
)
```

or you can give future builder a type parameter to cast it automatically as you made in 2nd code